# Is my proof correct? Prove that list of polynomials is basis (problem from Linear Algebra Done Right)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Suppose $p_0,p_1,...,p_m\in P(F)$ are such that each $p_j$ has degree $j$. Prove that $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is a basis of $P_m(F)$.

Notation: $F$ denotes the set of the complex numbers or real numbers. $P(F)$ denotes the set of all polynomials $F\mapsto F$. $P_m(F)$ denotes the set of all polynomials $F\mapsto F$ that have degree at most $m$.

Is this proof correct?:

$p_j=a_0p_0+a_1p_1+...+a_{j-1}p_{j-1}$ for some $a_k\in F$, for a $j\in\left\{1,2,...,m\right\}$$(*)$

implies the polynomial $p_j$ has the same degree as the polynomial $a_0p_0+a_1p_1+...+a_{j-1}p_{j-1}$.

The degree of $p_j$ is $j$; the degree of $a_0p_0+a_1p_1+...+a_{j-1}p_{j-1}$ is not greater than $j-1$. Contradiction in $(*)$.

Therefore the list $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is linearly independent in $P_m(F)$. This list has length $m+1=dim\ P_m(F)$. The polynomials $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ are contained in $P_m(F)$. These three facts imply in $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is basis of $P_m(F)$.

Note: If you found the statement "contradiction in $(*)$ implies $p_0,...,p_m$ is linearly independent" weird, here is a proof of this small theorem:

> $V$ is a vector space over $F$. A list of vectors $v_1,...,v_m$ in $V$ is linearly independent in $V$ if and only if there is no $v_j$ in that list such that $v_j=a_1v_1+...+a_{j-1}v_{j-1}$ for some $a's$ scalars because:
> 1.  $v_j=a_1v_1+...+a_{j-1}v_{j-1}$ for some $a's\in F$ implies the list is linearly dependent;
> 2. the list is linearly dependent implies there is $v_k$ such that $v_k=a_1v_1+...+a_{k-1}v_{k-1}+a_{k+1}v_{k+1}+...+a_mv_m(♥)$.
> Let $j$ be the biggest integer from 1 to m such that $a_j\neq 0$.
> $j<k$ implies $v_k$ can be written as linear combination of the vectors $v_1,...,v_{k-1}$. Let $j>k$. Swap $v_j$ and $v_k$ places in $(♥)$ and the equality $v_j=(-\frac{a_1}{a_j})v_1+(-\frac{a_2}{a_j})v_2+...+(-\frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j})v_{j-1}$ holds true, meaning that $v_j$ can be written as linear combination of the vectors $v_1,...,v_{j-1}$.

Comment: Seems ok to me.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think it's correct then. To help future students: this is an alternative solution for problem 10 in section 2.C Dimension of sheldon axler's book "Linear Algebra Done Right" 3rd edition